# Mvvm Light Dialog Message Box. How to Add Yes, No Instead of OK & Cancel?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am using mvvm light in my wp7 application but I am unsure how to get beyond the simple dialog box.

I have this in my code behind in my view

```
 Messenger.Default.Register<DialogMessage>(
             this,
             msg =>
             {
                 var result = MessageBox.Show(
                     msg.Content,
                     msg.Caption,
                     msg.Button);

                 // Send callback
                 msg.ProcessCallback(result);
             });
```

I have in my ViewModel something like this

```
  var message = new DialogMessage("Select Yes or No!", null)
        {
            Button = MessageBoxButton.OK,
            Caption = "Yes or No"
        };

        Messenger.Default.Send(message);
```

So how do I get it so it would have Yes or No?

Basically I need like the XNA dialog message just for MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

The message box is not related to MVVM Light or MVVM pattern. Basically viewmodel sends message to view through Messenger and upon receiving the message view responds by showing standard silverlight/windows phone message box. So I think, you'll need to use other message box (XNA or other third party libraries) since windows phone API only exposes OK/Cancel version of MessageBox class<sup>[[1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/3799b74f-f6be-4990-b154-a104f91d8865/messageboxbuttonyesno?forum=wpdevelop)]</sup>.

This is one of many example using XNA message box I found on net. You can use this in silverlight version of windows phone project by adding references to Microsoft.Xna.Framework and Microsoft.Xna. Framework.GamerServices :

Source :

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/delivering-message-using

Code :

```
Guide.BeginShowMessageBox("Version of Windows", "Pick a version of Windows.",
    new List<string> { "Vista", "Seven" }, 0, MessageBoxIcon.Error, 
    asyncResult => 
    {
        int? returned = Guide.EndShowMessageBox(asyncResult);
        Debug.WriteLine(returned.ToString());
    }, null);
```

**MVVM version :**

```
Messenger.Default.Register<DialogMessage>(
     this,
     msg =>
         {
             Guide.BeginShowMessageBox("Version of Windows", "Pick a version of Windows.",
                   new List<string> {"Vista", "Seven"}, 0, MessageBoxIcon.Error,
                   asyncResult =>
                       {
                           int? returned = Guide.EndShowMessageBox(asyncResult);
                           Debug.WriteLine(returned.ToString());
                       }, null);
         });
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Yep I know that is now related to MVVM Light or MVVM. What I mean is I need to somehow wrap the XNA dialog box so that it works with the MVVM patter. I am not sure how to wrap it though, If I can get away like the stand msg box or if something else more needs to be done as this XNA dialog box also has it's own callback so I would have to somehow pass in from MVVM that part as well.

Comment: I don't really understand. So you want to get whether user pressed "yes" or "no" on the message box in viewmodel using MVVM pattern? if that is the question, you can get dialog result in the view then send it to viewmodel using Messenger. And do you have a way to do that already in case of ok/cancel dialog box?

Comment: Right now as my code shows I have a dialog box that gets triggered from my View Model. The only problem is it is limited to "OK" & "Cancel". I want to trigger a dialog box from my View Model but I want it to say "Yes" or "No". I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Ok, I will try that when I have time the thing that jumps out at me is how do you get the  int? returned value back to your View Model?

Comment: not sure because this one is async, different from standard MessageBox. But you can try to replace `Debug.WriteLine...` with sending callback to viewmodel like `msg.ProcessCallback(returned);`. If that doesn't work, you can send returned value by sending message to viewmodel like I said in my 1st comment